# How to display chm help embedded in a vb6 project

Tags: vb6, chm

I developed a chm help file for my vb6 project. I added it by selecting the project properties. Which control can be used for displaying the chm help? Or can I do it through code without any controls?

Answer (score 2):

[How to implement chm Help to Visual Basic Applications](http://www.andreavb.com/tip020020.html)

Comment: Thats nice,but the problem is I cannot always copy the CHM file to application path(since i am distributing the application as package).

Comment: Just use the path you have instead of App.path. I don't see any problem. If the file is in a sort of archive, unarchive it to a temp folder.

Comment: OH...Sorry..I think U mistook me.By the statement "" I cannot always copy the CHM file to application path "" what I meant is that,I don't have the responsibility to copy files to a particular location(Since I will not be doing the installation.So the copying process is to be automated).

Comment: So you want to show a file which path is unknown... Good luck with that.